# Does context decide a subject and an object of an infinitive phrase when it is omitted? or is there any grammar rule about this?

Tags: to-infinitive

first, sorry for my poor English and I hope you can understand what I'm asking. It seems a subject of an infinitive phrase usually appears to be the same as that of a sentence.

For example

"I went to get help and by the time I got back he had stopped breathing." from lexico

"Sadly, she didn't live to see her grandchildren" from cambridge dictionary

but there are other cases like

when a subject of a sentence is an object of an infinitive phrase and a subject of it doesn't appear in the sentence:

"The plant is relatively easy to identify." from oxford learner's dictionary

"The sauce takes 25 minutes to prepare and cook." from collins dictionary

when a subject of a sentence is not a subject or an object of an infinitive phrase:

"The show may sound like one for the tourists, but passports are not required to get a ticket at the Olympia box office." from lexico

"A lot of patience is required to look after a disabled child." from longman dictionary

" It's too hot to go for a bike ride." from longman dictionary

when an object of a sentence is a subject of an infinitive phrase:

"The same lawyers told him to bring charges to a civil court and the sports court of arbitrage." from lexico

"Do you want me to take you to the airport?" from cambridge dictionary

So what makes it happen? Am I right to understand that context decides a subject and an object of an infinitive phrase when it is omitted? or is there any grammar rule about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways of identifying the *understood* **subject**: syntactic and non-syntactic.

In the former case, the subject can be identified by looking at a linguistic antecedent that appears in some particular function in the matrix (overall) construction, such as subject or object of a preposition. In the case of non-syntactic determination the meaning depends on other factors. It may be someone or something mentioned earlier in the discourse, or perhaps it applies quite generally. Compare:

> [1] *Ed promised* [*to resign from the board*].
>
> [2] *It is unwise* [*to go swimming straight after a meal*].

In [1] Ed did the promising, he is the subject of the verb "promise", and this is enough to tell us that "Ed" is also the subject of the verb "resign".

In [2], however, there is non-syntactic determination. The meaning depends heavily on inference. The salient interpretation is that it applies quite generally: "It is unwise for anyone to go swimming straight after a meal".

**Objects** are generally overt, but sometimes they are missing and have to be recovered from an antecedent expression. For example:

> [3] *You can inspect the house in a few days time*.
>
> [4] *The house will be ready* [*for you to inspect ___*] *in a few fays time*.

In [3] the object of "inspect" is clearly stated as "the house". But  in [4] the object (shown as ___) is missing. However, it is recoverable from earlier in the sentence, where it is obvious that what you will be inspecting is the house.